# Compatible laptop screen

Tags: laptop, display, resolution, laptop-display

My laptop screen was damaged and I would like to buy a new screen to replace it.

My laptop is a LDLC and I was not given information on the screen other than 15"6 matte 1600x900, but when I took it out I could read on it: "LG display" and "LP156WD1(TL)(B2)".

My question is the following: how can I know which screens are compatible, or do I need to buy exactly the same one? Subsidiary question: is it a bad idea to go for a higher resolution (like 1900*1080)? I am a bit worried about performance, all the more as my graphics card id badly supported by my Linux OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number you found on the inside is the correct number needed to determine the right screen needed for a replacement.

In some cases it's possible to upgrade the screen to one that has a higher resolution. But the chance is mostly not worth taking. This is because the video card might not recognize the new screen. And a host of different things.

I seemed to have found the screen you need at https://www.laptopscreen.com/English/screen-part-number/LP156WD1(TL)(B2)/

There are two different ones: the only difference is whether the screen has a matte finish or a glossy one.

Just as long as the numbers match up or if a screen is said to be compatible with the broken one you have now, it should be fine (Just in the case you don't wish to order from the website I found)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the specs from the laptop manufacturer to see what other resolution displays were available for that model. That will tell you what resolutions its graphics driver supports.
The performance difference will be minimal. Images will look nicer. Text will be harder to read because it will be slightly smaller. For matte/gloss question - that's entirely an individual preference.